# Constrain function argument to allocators using C++20 concepts

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, allocator

I wanted to constrain a constructor to take only allocators as arguments and I came up with this concept:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmgQAOqAqETgwe3r4BpClpjgKh4VEssfGJtpj2hQxCBEzEBFk%2BflyBdpgOGfWNBMWRMXEJHQ1NLTnttmP9YYNlw4kAlLaoXsTI7Bzm/mHI3lgA1Cb%2Bbk4KBMSYrCfYJhoAgjt7B5jHpxfEYcC390%2BJLy8RxObjYLBIAE9fo9ngx9kC3iCwZCAPpXBRrDaYaH/XZw17vNwANy6RGIONh8OBpzQcMwSQICgpAPxCMJXkctEIUP82EOAHoAFSHLD7IliQ6C/l/P4ETAsJIGOWEggQpKMVhvB60WioURk27HR60zYMw54BQosS6/Ukd4AEUOVwAjl48OiINqbUwyYcmEtjgB2KyPQ5hw6q9XMNiHL16n0kEAgcXeTAoyPY/whh7hoMWP0AOmt8blEAu6CTotoKZB5aTaQAXmmCLcIEsAyZA46ALSGusgBSaq1M04Z6NanUlxPJsReZtqzCC35Zv65zv5pgFrDF/WYMsECsgKs10cL8exye2%2BIz1PphetlaHfvHsS1g/1vBN9MPjtdw693kn3fAchyYEdiVQPB0GXbNO3tE5YMeOUFSVRFTyjTVDgAFRxT4vAcQ4AFkITjK881XcMvDSIxDhTOc73VB1sIQiiwyYDlUD9S8fT3ftG2bJ9P0wAMAL5LClxXUNw3YogRWubjS3E0ggMPfj00EpsRMNIlIOgySni7FiYUeMICEOFgmDCNtyKksMqO%2BWMuCY/sdwTclTlMmDWMOeyaIeMxnOApIWGvFJaAhcFiCSBA8GQK0FJIN9D2iCE5S82yfOo4BDnzE5HWI0i3JBTzeSMnNKKyw43EC1TLm%2BMqZQyvAqEOWkLkwVQkmICALXi70DVOB4uFuX9s1zXN%2BzQDlCRBY4zDMIbzQUP0GC4/rEvmmbThUpNXFoMq10MpqWrauVOu63rXIGtx/JGmzyvGnaUDWMyQVm8wFoCi0VrWqdyU2t7tv7PaDvDODvOa1qBHa86estK7EtOKxeVG7yJuAqbXtOd75vzb7DF%2Bq8Pq26rgYYdB9v0w74OOqGGBhrq4b6v6QTcO71zR8NJpekm5rMar8dWhH/oCwHSeAkGqbBo6DPtDgVloTgAFZeD8DgtFIVBODZyxrCfTFNjm/weFIAhNHllYAGsQCVjR9E4SRVfNzXOF4BQQDts31fl0g4FgGBEGehU6DichKDQYP6HiYAFGYJIFAQVACFILAiVizAADU8EwAB3AB5KNOBNmhaDlYh3YgaJneiMJGghIveBr5hiAhPPom0UkG9ICO2EEPOGHC52sGiLxgDca13e4XgsAsoxxG9lP3VJPASUnjWOq6Dktg10zqmdrlomIOuPCwZ26pYBuVioAwY6z3OC8YLv%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUBfdC4fQhhjDWGsPoPA0R3aQBWKgBkGRJ7dnLHlUwutLBmA0P%2BPOCheCoBJMQL4WBIFtiqDUDILhyYTDaEEcmAxSjlD0PkdIAgKH0NSIwhgNChjxAAZ0boAhejjE8K0PQPDaj8NmCUThwiZjMO4TMDhCwuErAxOsTYEgFbKydgvLWHBDiqAABwADZuwGMkIcYAyBkCHAgJcLwDBLYBggLgQgdodhcCWLwL2Wh2ykGtrbe2HBHakAvkrSQBZJAAE5AzhI0FEiJUSYnhNIGrDW2i3Ye1NubFYftA4vSSByMOEAI5JBDsQCImpOD6KMSYsxFjDjtALCbTA%2BAyRQT0M/YQohxAf3ad/NQzt/6kBzkfJIl9/EqySc7bRecOR5LMqgFqlTjGmPMZY6xxBbH2KsR4SOcQjZuI8ZklYCBrhYHiEQxWATeAX0kErAsts0HhLQfcjQjyAHJOwa7Ww6TPEWx8TbO2Fz/CaJSZ8n53iLlmGBR8jgBzvbeNwWkZwkggA%3D%3D%3D)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <vector>
#include <concepts>
#include <utility> /* declval */

template <typename Allocator> 
concept is_allocator = requires(Allocator a) {
    typename Allocator::value_type;
    { a.allocate(std::declval<std::size_t>()) } -> std::same_as<typename Allocator::value_type*>;
    { a.deallocate(std::declval<typename Allocator::value_type>(), std::declval<std::size_t>()) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template <typename T>
struct MyAllocator {
    using value_type = T;
    auto allocate(std::size_t size) -> T*;
    auto deallocate(T*, std::size_t size) -> void;
};

int main() {
    using A1 = std::allocator<int>;
    using A2 = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;
    using B = MyAllocator<int>;
    using C = std::string;


    if constexpr(is_allocator<A1>) {
        std::cout << "A1 is an allocator" << std::endl;
    }
    if constexpr(is_allocator<A2>) {
        std::cout << "A2 is an allocator" << std::endl;
    }
    if constexpr(is_allocator<B>) {
        std::cout << "B is an allocator" << std::endl;
    }
    if constexpr(is_allocator<C>) {
        std::cout << "C is an allocator" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I expected it to detect allocators in A1, A2, B and C case but it doesn't detect a single allocator. Why does this concept not hold true?

Comment: Looks like you might have a typo at the end of `std::declval<typename Allocator::value_type>()`. Seems like it should be `value_type*`.

Comment: There is no need to use `std::declval` in your example, and it will be much more concise to write these parameters together in the parameter list of the `requires`-clause.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Could you show me I'm not really adept in concepts? :/

Comment: @glades Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/qffbGxrxh).

Comment: @康桓瑋 Oh that's much prettier, thanks! :D

Comment: You might replace your debug display with `if constexpr` by `static_assert` (which also show the expectation).

Answer (score 2):

My bad, forgot a '*'... Here's the corrected version that works correctly (credits to @康桓瑋 for more conciseness)!

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIJIapAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcQm2mPaOAkIETMQEWT5%2BXJXVGXUNBEUR0bF6CvWNzTltQ929JWUSAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJutuTkPEmKwH2CYaAIIbWzuY%2B4cnocAXV7dmmwzbXnsHbjYLBIAE93jc7j8Hk9AZhgcQQQB9U4KRbLTDgz7fX7/Q4AN0wDhImMhOMeALQP0wSQIChJNwIcKSBkZMIIIKSjFYj2utFoqFERGIF32N0pKxpuzwCkRYn5gpITwAIrtTgBHLx4FEQXnyphC3ZMUi7dmc5hsXa6gX6kggEB4sReTCI02YABUuySs32AHYrDddoHfRZDQA6OXWxkQDTekw%2BlUAWhFQ3QdoU3NldMOWG2rogXve6391yDwbDWAjgsw%2BeNMd9ieTBFTIHTbEzALxqDw6ELxbjSoOfYZTJZ5MOrvNjwAKpiTl4HLsALIgq0K4jBj6lrxpIy7B3eZ2u5W7GdFzdBpheIiGvmR6sptN4ABeh92aRf3qT62wJ7dg/PgaXteFa3lWEBTm6xoPi2z6vu%2BmCfiKnbdv%2BELxqhtw3KEBC7CwTChBAsZ%2BgBuzbq8lpcMe0GVjawqHNhvYkWRu7XGYVFNnaSQsHEIApLQILwkkCB4MgsqgbRALQVEIKMoxAZBsxwC7CGBwqsuq4SfRghySWCk7kpbjsc2LxGBhHwkXgVC7JSQyYKoSTEBA0piXqQoAtcXAXERxalqW0FoFeMIAvsZhmB5UoKIaDA3q5xKhUFhxvhxICuLQGGlv2FlWTZjL2Y5zk0W5hysV5G7yb5SXNgFOEAsF5hhWx0pRTFkZxWxtWJdBqXpUGmXlVK2UCLZeVOTKhXEocVjft5JF%2Bcl1UJYZ9Uhk1hgtWu9WLZVdrdWe/V9bpgaWdZQ25Q5o0ua1dFuG4pVxj5FXbSgiw1YcdWhYZq3ReNwrxR1hldQw6BpXth31uZ8YcPMtCcAArLwfgcFopCoJwt2WNYb5oisIXrDwpAEJoUPzAA1iAABs6yhj6kg%2BusGg%2BgAnOTAAckhcOskiM9IMMcJICNEyjnC8AoICJITSNQ6QcCwDAiDPSwSR0LE5CUGgivK3EwAKMwSQKAgqAEKQWB4iJmAAGp4JgADuADyZqcPjNC0IyxCixAUSC1EoQNCCju8N7zAIrbUTaISEv4%2BrbCCLbDD8YLWBRF4wBuHKovcLwWB4UY4iS8bWrh3gBLp8jdmEleqzI9hVSC7QeBRMQvseFggsEMQeAsP78xUAY2uWzb9uMP7MiCCIYjsFII/yEoaiC7obQGEYKDWNY%2Bj16LkDzKgNIZOnCYpqppgY5YZgaLsCa2wovCoASxDt1gG%2BEe0hfOBArijK0gRA1M/RxG0KRpBqJkTwLQ9AAIKAwH%2BpQBjjCqC/BgXQRggLGM/BwnRhg9FCH0aBf9bAYI/oMDBUCZhcHmKiJYKw5j6DhgLPOqMOC7FUCzcmCZyaSF2MAZAyBdgQDbl4BgJNvQQFwIQRUGxSG8AlloWYpMQCw0SLzfmpBO6w0kKGLmTMGbc0ZpopmpBEbI3oSLMWBMibzBlvLF6SQryqwgOrJW9BiDhG5JwJhLC2EcK4bsDmoZ8aYHwEKbseh%2BCj1EOISeITp4qHUHneepBraNySF3ahHB4b6MFvQ22V5rE4VQFZNxrD2GcO4bw4g/DBE8I8BrRxuMJGmMljI0gCAzhYDiE/RRvBO6SFhqGeRp9Ganz6RoAZbQDHX2FrYExUjiakDJuscmoYzCwzMOTAZGg8aw2YfI8mKT1i0MMRM6ZjTeZmH2eMjgkizHzFvmkZwkggA)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <vector>
#include <concepts>

template <typename Allocator> 
concept is_allocator = requires(Allocator a, typename Allocator::value_type* p) {
    { a.allocate(0) } -> std::same_as<decltype(p)>;
    { a.deallocate(p, 0) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template <typename T>
struct MyAllocator {
    using value_type = T;
    auto allocate(std::size_t size) -> T*;
    auto deallocate(T*, std::size_t size) -> void;
};

int main() {
    using A1 = std::allocator<int>;
    using A2 = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;
    using B = MyAllocator<int>;
    using C = std::string;


    if constexpr(is_allocator<A1>) {
        std::cout << "A1 is an allocator" << std::endl;
    }
    if constexpr(is_allocator<A2>) {
        std::cout << "A2 is an allocator" << std::endl;
    }
    if constexpr(is_allocator<B>) {
        std::cout << "B is an allocator" << std::endl;
    }
    if constexpr(is_allocator<C>) {
        std::cout << "C is an allocator" << std::endl;
    }
}
```